# How do i change date to timestamp for already save records?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have already saved only Date in database using hibernate. Now  I need to save time along with date. How should I do for already saved records with date? How do I change date to timestamp for already save records?

Comment: Show us the DDL for the table and the related entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate with annotations just add another annotation
  **@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )**  along with your **@Column**. 
Then your annotataiion will look something like this:-

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
@Column( name = "event_start_time")
public Date getEventStartTime()
{
   return eventStartTime;
}
```

In case you want to change it back to date you instead of removing the annotation change the value to **TemporalType.DATE**

Comment: Thanks. but, I am not using annotations.

Comment: i am having createdDate column in the table. and its data type is Date. Now i need to change form Date to Timestamp. any answer? I have records in the table with date. If i change it to timestamp what about previous records having only date?

Comment: Yes you have to change the date column to Timestamp in the table and previous records will be something like this 01-01-2015 00:00:00.  And you need to change the type in your hbm file for date column to java.sql.Timestamp and change the Field type from Date to Timestamp in corresponding java class as well.